Auto populate static date in Excel
I am currently using =IF(ISBLANK(A3),"",NOW()) to auto populate date in Excel. But every time after saving it and I open it again it changes the date in the entire column.
I need it to stay the same date from when the cell (A3) was initially filled in.

I think that requires a VBA solution, or use CTRL + ; for manual insertion.

So many solutions in the forum, have you tried to research ? here

Please check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77449284/is-there-a-formula-that-would-automatically-insert-a-static-date
